# Splitting a very large string

Tags: c#, string, hex

I'm looking for a C# code to split a very large string (hex values) into 8-size chunks (array of strings) so that I could turn them into ints one by one.

The hex value string looks like `...000000030000000800000002...` and I want them in `00000003`, `00000008`, `00000002`, etc.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Note that if your goal to get list of `int` and not split the string you'd better use approaches suggested in [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa?rq=1) to avoid creation (even lazy creation as in duplicate question) of the intermediate string altogether.

Answer (score 1):

this is a easy to understand version:

```
string x = "0000000100000002000000003";

List<string> a = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i += 8)
{
    if((i + 8) < x.Length)
        a.Add(x.Substring(i, 8));
    else
        a.Add(x.Substring(i));
}
```

result is:

```
a[0] = 00000001;
a[1] = 00000002;
a[2] = 00000003;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this maybe what you're looking for:

```
string sentence = "0000000100000002000000003";
string[] digits = Regex.Split(sentence, ".{8}");
```

**Result:**

```
digits[0] = "00000001"
digits[1] = "00000002"
digits[2] = "00000003"
```

Comment: +0: Using regex + creating a lot of strings at the same time... You need to add explanation of regex you are using - don't assuming that everyone knows its syntax.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Usually i will agree with you, and almost always will favor the iterative way rather the recursive or in this case Regular expression way. I still publish this scenario because someone else already publish iterative `Substring` scenario, so i used this stage to show another implementation for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String.Split method on your string like so:

```
string longString = "10101010,10101010,10101010"
string[] Array;
Array = longString.Split(",");
```

To get the comma separated string, you could use @Sameer's Regex idea.

Comment: Or maybe it was String.Split(longString, ",");